# Method to find coordinates of where image is cropped

Tags: adobe-photoshop, imagemagick

Here's my problem: I'm working with a tool that automatically crops an image that i supply to it. I need to find out exactly which coordinates of the image does the tool crop?

Right now i used photoshop to find some estimated coords but since i have about 100 different types of images whos cropping coords i need (And very precisely), that's not very practical.

I can supply an estimated bounding box and the real cropping coords should be within ~10 pixels of the box's edges. The box is small, 100x100 pixels at maximum. I'm thinking something along the lines of applying a different colour to every pixel in a demo image, wondering how i can do that in photoshop or if there's a better way.

Comment: What tool are you using to automatically crop the image?  Why do you need the coordinates of the crop? What are you hoping to achieve with these?  Can you supply some example images perhaps?  What do you mean by a "demo image"?

Comment: @BillyKerr I'm using an internal tool that requires you to upload an image, it then automatically splits that image into 3 seperate images.. I need to find out what coordinates it crops the image at so that i can make a script that allows me to automatically set up a document that gets cropped properly. A sample image would be http://imgur.com/a/qjkqI, the internal tool automatically grabs the photo, signature and handwriting from that. I need to find out what coordinates that tool crops the images at.

Comment: @BillyKerr As for a demo image, i mean upload a special image onto that tool with markings of some sort that'd let me know what coordinates the image was cropped at.

Comment: You can measure exact pixel locations in Photoshop using the Info panel. see [here](http://imgur.com/a/gncx2)

Answer (score 1):

- Create the image to the size you want to submit
- Make a horizontal "Hue" gradient (with value=100%)
- Add a layer, make a vertical black to white color gradient, and set layer mode to "Multiply" or ("Value").
- Flatten image

You now have an image where Hue and Value are determined by the position of the pixel in the image you submit.